# Is it possible to determine the type of input from the input handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have an event handler for [the 'input' even](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)t:

```
inputEl.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    log('yaay!')
});
```

I need to do something *just* for paste. I know I could make a [separate event handler for 'paste' only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste), however I share code for most types of inputs and would like to avoid extra listeners if not necessary. Is it possible - for example, by checking a property of the `event` object, to see if a `input` event was initiated by pasting?

Comment: You can use `jQuery`, plain javascript has no way to handle multiple events except multiple handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, there is no way to do that without binding a separate event listener.

The event object has no "input type" methods that I can see in the log, so just checking for an input you cannot determine if typed or pasted. It's just plain input.

For example (from a deleted answer I saw), checking say, `event.type` in the input listener will yield `input` whether you typed or pasted.

Comment: Do you want to get marked as an answer? Because that's how you get marked as an answer.